# How to have page specific styles for parent class in react

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a couple of wrapper html elements in my app.tsx file. I have a default styling for the outermost "main-content" container, but I want to style it differently for a specific page.

The reason I am having trouble doing that now is:

The router component is a child of "main-content", so I can't create a class name for the component I am creating in order to selectively style "main-content".

Is there some way I can include an internal stylesheet inside of a specific component, so that I can affect its parent class?

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementsByClassName('className').style = your_style.` Inside your `componentWIllMount()` method for that specific component